# C# - programming scrolling live graph

Tags: c#, scroll, charts

I'm programming a live graph application that uses Chart as graph.

My graph is auto scrolling according to X axis, but it shows an ugly scroll bar.
I wanted to know how to hide this scroll bar and keep auto scrolling the graph.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 400;
```

This is the timer that adding points to the graph:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum > chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size)
        {
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum);
        }
        this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeStamp, rnd.Next(min, max + 1));
        timeStamp += timer1.Interval;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lol, found a solution:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = false;
```

lol i feel like an idiot :)